# Django - how to use json file with django

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap with django, so I have all the CSS and Javascript set up.  And I am using this code in my html file.

```
<table data-url="data1.json" data-height="299" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id" data-align="right" data-sortable="true">Item ID</th>
            <th data-field="name" data-align="center" data-sortable="true">Item Name</th>
            <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Item Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

However, I want to link this json file http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/data1.json in data-url="the link".  How would I do that?

Comment: Just replace the URL. The question is too vague. Consider adding more details.

Answer (score 0):

i tried your code with bootstrap and django.
set bootstrap-table.css and bootstrap-table.js.
and set url by your link.

In my case, safari browser console said this.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/data1.json?order=asc&_=1439125849853. 
Origin http://127.0.0.1:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

if you are looking for this, i think this is cross domain problem.
you should download to your localhost data1.json
and then, set url to 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/data1.json' or etc..

your question is too simple, so nobody can answer that..